# Using a counter to display percentage

Tags: vba, percentage

How do I code this so it displays a percentage out of a hundred? Visual basic

```
MsgBox("Percantage: " & (correctQuestions + wrongQuestions) / 2)
```

Comment: In what language are you programming?

Comment: Basic math: `precentage_of_correct_questions = (correct_questions / total_questions) * 100`. More info: http://www.mathsisfun.com/percentage.html.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is `MsgBox("Percentage: " & Round(100 * (correctQuestions + wrongQuestions) / 2) & "%")`

Where I've used Round() to remove any decimal part; for up to 2 decimal places, for example, use

`MsgBox("Percentage: " & Round(100 * (correctQuestions + wrongQuestions) / 2, 2) & "%")`

But note that all your formula is doing is displaying half the total number of questions; assuming they are either correct or wrong.

Comment: The problem is i keep getting errors when i attempt to use round

Comment: what are the data types and values of correctQuestions and wrongQuestions? What error are you getting?

Comment: If TextBox1.Text = num1 * num2 Then
            ' If they get the answer right, they recieve postive feedback
            Label2.Text = "Correct!!11"
            ' adds up the correct answers
            correctQuestions += 1
            total +=1

        Else
            ' Any other answer results in negative feedback
            Label2.Text = "Incorrect, sorry about that"
            ' adds up the wrong answer
            wrongQuestions += 1
            total += 1
            ' after every question, a msgbox will appear and let the user know there progress
Here is an example